# Google Sheets Script : Automatically remove a row into another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am currently using google forms to enable users to submit site changes. This is all working beautifully.

I have added an extra column that has ticket status. Now I have written a script that checks for when this is updated to Done and then moves that row into another sheet entitled done.

However this only works if i update a row that i manually added. If I change the column on a row created from the form entry it will not work. Has anyone seen this issue before. Code is below.

```
function onEdit(e){

  /*
   When a user updates a status to done the ticket gets moved to another sheet
  */
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Form responses 1"; // The sheet to watch for changes
  var columnNumberToWatch = 1; // The column where the change happens on the above sheet
  var valueToWatch = "Done"; // What is the text you are looking for
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Done"; // The Sheet name for where the row gets moved to.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get the active spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Get the active sheet
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell(); // Get the current cell that has just been updated

  // Check that you are on the correct sheet and column. 
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo); // get a reference for the target sheet
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); // get a reference for the target row
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange); // copy the row from current sheet to the new sheet
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow()); // Delete the row from the old sheet
  }

}
```

Comment: If you indent 4 spaces, or highlight your code and then press the {} symbol in the editing bar, your code will be offset with a much much easier to read format.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the onEdit function won't fire unless you do it manually, you'll want to use the [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger, which will fire when a form response is received.  This is a manually installed trigger connected to your form, which should be able to do the function above pretty much as written.

```
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
     .forForm(form)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
```

To be safe, though, you may want to define your spreadsheet, sheet, and range by id or by name rather than by whether they are active, I believe getActiveWhatever() kinds of methods will return null if the spreadsheet isn't open.

Comment: I have tried changing this to an formsubmit trigger however this also does not work.

The issues seems to be with the rows on that sheet. If I manually add a row and update the status column to Done. It workes fine , It only seems to not work when I am changing a row that was created from a form submission.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, using active is not the best idea.

Instead of:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get the active spreadsheet 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Get the active sheet 
var range = sheet.getActiveCell(); // Get the current cell that has just been updated
```

Try:

```
var range = e.range;
var sheet = range.getSheet();
var ss = sheet.getParent();
```

If you try this you cannot execute it from the code editor because no event is passed. You must execute it by actually submitting a form.